# Form not being validated in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to validate the user's input by linking a JS file to validate the inputs. However, when I click the submit button with erroneous data, the form is submitted and no validation error is given.

The form:

```
<form id="user_form" name="contactForm" action="#" method="GET" onsubmit="return validateForm();">

<p id="first_name" class="input_title">First name <span class="asterisk_red">*</span></p>

<!-- The HTML 5 'Required' attribute will not allow the form to be sent empty. -->
<input class="input_box" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Joe" />

<input id="submit_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```

And the JS I use to validate:

```
function validateForm(){

/* Validate the first name field of the form */
var fn = document.forms['contactForm'].first_name.value;

/* If the Name string is empty then return false and show warning. */
if (fn == ""){
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    document.forms['contactForm'].first_name.reset();
    return false;
}else if(fn.length <= 2){
    alert("Your first name must more than two characters");
    document.forms['contactForm'].first_name.reset();
    return false;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can call reset() on an element. I think you use that method on form object to clear all the fields. IE and FF doesn't seem to have a problem but Chrome seem to. As a result, chrome doesn't execute the javascript and submits the form always. Here is fiddle [Form Submit](http://jsfiddle.net/ubjTH/6/) and the updated code:

```
function validateForm() {

            /* Validate the first name field of the form */
            var fn = document.forms['contactForm'].first_name.value.trim();

            /* If the Name string is empty then return false and show warning. */
            if (fn == "") {
                alert("First name must be filled out");
                document.forms['contactForm'].first_name.value = '';//Removed reset
                return false;
            } else if (fn.length <= 2) {
                alert("Your first name must more than two characters");
                document.forms['contactForm'].first_name.value = '';//Removed reset
                return false;
            }
            return true;//Added
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. When I submit the form with the first_name input box containing three space characters, the form is submitted. In the URI it contains: contact.html?first_name=+++. I think the '+' represents the space characters and that they get counted as actual characters because they the spaces are converted into the '+'. Could that be possible?

Comment: You can use trim(). See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubjTH/8/). But please be aware that IE 8 and below do not support trim(). However, you can extend the prototype to implement your own trim function for browsers where it is not supported.

Comment: Yup trim() worked. And thanks for the compatibility issue with IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

please check this result: [Form Validation jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGRyn/)
you have the form validation with more inputs and with GET.

And also see Jquery reference about how to build a  [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Or just use plugin validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate();
  });
```

Comment: the op is not using jquery

Answer (score -1):

You can just use a normal button in your form and use a javascript function to submit the form.

Comment: Even when I change the button to a HTML button element, the form is submitted without validating.

Comment: did you remove the submit type?

Comment: Yes I have the button like this: <button id="submit_button" name="submit">Submit </button>

Comment: I would try to set the form tag to return false and let the button run the submission off the form, otherwise I am out for the moment.I think javascript also has a native function called preventdefault.